# Why wasn't the Z6 version of the Infocom Z-machine ported to the IIgs?

Tags: history, apple-ii, gaming, apple-iigs

Infocom ported their Z-machine to nearly every viable platform in the 70s and 80s. Zork runs on around 18 different 8/16 bit platforms using earlier versions of the Z-machine. Why was Z6 the graphical version of the Z-machine ported to the Apple II, but not the IIgs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect it was too late in the game for Infocom... The Apple II port of `YZIP`, Infocom’s Z6 interpreter, was released in 1989 (as far as I can determine), and by then Infocom was only a publishing house inside Activision, and was about to be shut down entirely.

I imagine that, given the limited development resources available, Infocom would have preferred porting the interpreter to entirely new platforms (new to `YZIP` anyway, such as the Atari ST), before spending time creating a IIGS-specific port (since the IIGS could run the Apple II interpreter just fine, in IIe mode). There were only four games affected by this anyway ([Arthur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur:_The_Quest_for_Excalibur), [Journey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_(1989_video_game)), [Shōgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Clavell%27s_Sh%C5%8Dgun), and [Zork Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zork_Zero))...

The IIGS did get specific ports of Z-machine interpreters later on, for [The Lost Treasures of Infocom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Treasures_of_Infocom), but they only support [Z3 and Z5 games](http://apple2.org.za/gswv/a2zine/Sel/LostTreasures.htm) (so Zork Zero, which was part of the compilation on other platforms, isn’t included in the IIGS version). I can only guess why these didn’t support Z6, but I suspect that the effort involved was deemed too great for a single game (LTOI 1 included Zork Zero, and the floppy-based releases of LTOI 2, which were only released on the Mac and PC anyway, didn’t include a single Z6 game).

Comment: Yes, but The Lost Treasures of Infocom was a significant port to the IIgs, so Z6 could have been ported then.

Comment: But not by Infocom; or was your question more general than only Infocom?

Comment: For that matter, if the question *is* intended to be open-ended in that manner, then it's based on a partly faulty premise. The Frotz interpreter *has* been ported to the GS and, at least according to [this page](http://apple2.org.za/gswv/a2zine/Sel/InfocomTypeGames3.htm), has at least partial Z6 support on the platform.

Comment: @jmbpiano The Frotz doesn't support z6 graphics so it's not full support for z6. Support for z7-z8 is useful for more recent text adventures but leaves a hole around graphics. So my question stands that nobody has a full z6 z-machine for the IIgs, either ported by Infocom or a third party.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin - if the IIe Z6 interpreter runs on a IIgs in compatibility mode, what's the benefit of building a IIgs-native version?

Comment: @scruss compare [the Apple II screenshots of Zork Zero](https://www.mobygames.com/game/apple2/zork-zero-the-revenge-of-megaboz/screenshots) to [the Amiga versions](https://www.mobygames.com/game/amiga/zork-zero-the-revenge-of-megaboz/screenshots)... A IIGS-specific port would have benefited from the higher resolution, even if it didn’t provide any more colours.

Comment: The IIgs version of Lost Treasures was handled by Big Red Computer
Club, not Activision/Infocom.  However, a IIgs version of Beyond Zork
(Z5) WAS released by Infocom in 1988.  BZ appears to be C code compiled with APW C.  LT was compiled with ORCA/C. BRCC said they were "unable to obtain a license for" the Z6 interpreter. Possibly as part of their license deal, BRCC only had access to the IIgs BZ source code

Comment: There was speculation that BRCC used the InfoTaskForce zmachine (the [IFT wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfoTaskForce) claims that as well)
but I don't believe that's correct. Some of the internal error messages match up between the BZ and LT interpreters (eg, "Undefined shift state - putstr") and don't match messages from IFT.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Kelvin. I’ve been poking around the BRCC interpreters, and they do appear to be licensed from Infocom (they have “Copyright (c) 1986 Infocom, Inc.” notices), I wonder why BRCC couldn’t get a license for YZIP. [The Infocom Fact Sheet](http://pdd.if-legends.org/infocom/fact-sheet.txt) suggests there may have been a IIGS port of YZIP at Infocom, but I haven’t been able to find out any more about that.